# Python list of lists// Pyspark

Tags: python, list, pyspark, bigdata, rdd

Input:

```
[['A', 'V1'], ['A', 'V2'], ['B', 'V6'], ['B', 'V7']]
```

How can I get the below output for the above input

Expected output:

```
listA = ['V1', 'V2'],  listB = ['V6', 'V7']
```

Additional information:

I am learning pyspark and

```
[('X', [['A', 'V1'], ['A', 'V2'], ['B', 'V6'], ['B', 'V7']]),
 ('Y', [['A', 'V3'], ['A', 'V4'], ['B', 'V8']])]
```

is where I am at as of now. I am trying to implement join without using the join function.

X and Y are my keys based on which I want to join. A and B are the different file sources.

My expected final output is:

```
(X, ['V1', 'V6'])
(X, ['V1', 'V7'])
(X, ['V2', 'V6'])
(X, ['V2', 'V7'])
(Y, ['V3', 'V8'])
(Y, ['V4', 'V8'])
```

Comment: 1. Is the question about implementing this in Python lists or in Pyspark? 2. what do you mean with A and B are different source files? They look strings to me in the examples you provide. 3. from the expected output, you are looking for all the combinations of values in A and B. 4. "I am trying to implement join without using the join function" is not consistent with your output, that is not a "join". I am really lost here!

Comment: Are you implementing this in Pyspark? They seems like some operations on RDDs.. coudnt understand your expectation on join output. I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sophisticated, but something like those lines may help you:

```
list = [['A', 'V1'], ['A', 'V2'], ['B', 'V6'], ['B', 'V7']]

list_a = []
list_b = []
for i in list:
    first, second = i
    if first == 'A':
        list_a.append(second)
    elif first == 'B':
        list_b.append(second)

print("list_a: ", list_a)
print("list_b: ", list_b)
```